# How to Minimize Apache Cordova App loading time

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am new to Cordova apps,Right now I am developing an app on SAPUI5 using cordova, When I run it on android its taking 7-8 seconds to load,I tried minify css and js but it didn't help.Here is my HTML code.

```
`<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>

        <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
        </script>
        <!-- only load the mobile lib "sap.m" and the "sap_bluecrystal" theme -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/myCSS.css">

        <script>
        var user = "xxxx";
        var pass = "xxxx";
        var gatewayLoginLink = "proxy/http/xxxxxx/sap/opu/odata/sap/xxxxx";
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel( gatewayLoginLink, true, user, pass));

        </script>


        <script>
                sap.ui.localResources("qrcode");
                var app = new sap.m.App({initialPage:"idqrcode1"});
                var page = sap.ui.view({id:"idqrcode1", viewName:"qrcode.qrcode", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML});
                app.addPage(page);
                app.placeAt("content");
        </script>   
     <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>`
```

please help.

Comment: You can try to reduce the package size and the files it loads which are not needed. The library by default loads all the controls ( i guess). So, read through this link. Delete the unnecessary files. Link - https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/29/3eb945f0e945aaa776812481b4c533/content.htm

Comment: I have deleted all the unnecessary files,it has reduced the size of application by 4mb ,and now it is taking 4-5 secs to load ,can I still decrease the loading time?

Comment: I see that you are creating odata model in Index.html. I would suggest you take it out and put it in index.js after the app is initialised. Before app is initialised, everything works in syncronous mode.